# Efficient Breadcrumbs On Rails Multi Model Tree?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, breadcrumbs

I am new to rails and unclear about how to efficiently display breadcrumbs on a multi model tree hierarchy. My app tree is 7 models/levels deep but I will illustrate with 3.

```
class One
 has_many :twos

class Two
 belongs_to :one
 has_many :threes

class Three
 belongs_to :two
```

For example, say I want breadcrumbs on a show three view (linking to the parent instances of two and one). I am currently using AR associations in the controller:

```
add breadcrumb @three.two
add breadcrumb @three.two.one
```

This works fine except two additional SQL queries are run (to retrieve the two and one ancestors).

How can I have breadcrumbs more efficiently?

[Unfortunately, the Ancestry gem only seems to work with one model but is the idea of serialising the breadcrumb into a column worth pursuing? This is such a basic requirement that I suspect I am over complicating this out of ignorance.]

Comment: This gem may be of service to you: https://github.com/zachinglis/crummy

Comment: @craig.kaminsky - thanks, I have looked at various breadcrumb gems. I do not see that this gem addresses my question - it would still require the additional SQL calls in my example.

Comment: My apologies, when I looked at the gem, I thought you were able to just add the breadcrumb details at the top of the Controller and those would be picked up/built along the way. Again, apologies for the incorrect response.